# How to assign the key and values using hashmap?

Tags: groovy, hashmap

Lets say, I am fetching the data from excel and I need to map two things.

ID and the corresponding Dates, Excel data look like this :-

```
       ID                             Dates
      N1#N1          2018-10-09,2018-10-10#2018-10-11
```

Actual output should look like this :-

```
{N1=2018-10-09,2018-10-10} {N1=2018-10-11}
```

I have tried below code:-

```
//Fetching from using in soap ui    
String id = context.expand('${Data#ID}')
String dt = context.expand('${Data#Dates}')

List arrId = id.split('#')

def strD

LinkedHashMap < String, String > dateMap= new LinkedHashMap < 
String, String > ()
for(int i=0; i<arrId.size(); i++) {
strD = dt.split("#").asType(List)[i]

dateMap.put(arrId[i],strD)

}

log.info dateMap
```

Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: what language is that? it doesn't even come close to valid java syntax

Comment: Your code is valid/working to me. Are you facing some execution error? Can you provide more details?

Comment: Ok, just give ID as N1 only. like this:- N1#N1 .. Still is it working? @Edumelzer

Comment: Hey, this is groovy actually.. @Stultuske

Comment: @avidCoder Ok, now I get a Map with just N1 and a single date record (like this:  ([N1:2018-10-11]). In this case do you want the dates to be merged?

Comment: No, No... I want this to be printed like this: - {N1=2018-10-09,2018-10-10} {N1=2018-10-11} ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def ids = "N1#N1".split('#')
def dts = "2018-10-09,2018-10-10#2018-10-11".split('#')

List<Map> result = (0..ids.size()-1).collect{
   [(ids[it]): dts[it]]
}

assert result == [[N1:"2018-10-09,2018-10-10"], [N1:"2018-10-11"]]
```

Comment: hey, this is fine.. my code works with my code only.. I need ids to be N1#N1.. I have edited the questions. (Typo error)

Comment: Another try I gave is, by importing org.apache.commons.collections.map.MultiValueMap; And assigning inside dataMap.. But here, result is like this - {N1=[2018-10-09,2018-10-10, 2018-10-11]}

Comment: Map always have unique keys. Probably you need list of maps ? Updated answer

Comment: Thanks.. it worked, Can my code be converted the same way?

Comment: Yes, but you need to change it a little

Comment: I tried, but not able to replicate.. could you please help me to replicate this?